# Delay jquery function / form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, delay

im struggling to get a function to be delayed for 3 seconds.. this is on an image -

```
 function base64_tofield() {

            $('#formfield').val($.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());

             document.form.submit();
           };
```

ive tried:

```
setTimeout( function () { 
          base64_tofield(); 
           }, 3000);
```

to no avail. the form is just submitting without the 3 second delay - any ideas? do i need to 'block' the form or what?

thanks!

image code:

```
<img id="btn1" onclick="base64_tofield()">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vhsce/)** : alert will popup after 3 secs.

Try this:

```
<img id="btn1" onclick="new_fun()">

function new_fun()
{
    setTimeout( function () { 
          base64_tofield(); 
    }, 3000);
}

function base64_tofield() {
    $('#formfield').val($.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    document.form.submit();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function with a timeout like this

```
setTimeout(base64_tofield, 3000);
```

Comment: tx - but now it submits the form every 3 seconds now by itself it seems.. do i put that outside the base64_tofield?

    function base64_tofield() {
                $('#formfield').val($.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
                document.form.submit();
           };
           setTimeout(base64_tofield, 3000);

Comment: Yes. Put it outside, otherwise its going to be recursive

Answer (score 1):

> "do i need to 'block' the form or what?"

Euh, yes that sounds like an idea. Right now you define your function `base64_tofield()` directly without the use of jquery. Any reason for that?

In jQuery the event parameter is added which allows you to do `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("#btn1").click(function(event){
    // do i need to 'block' the form or what?
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(base64_tofield, 3000);
});
```

Not sure how your images are added to the page but a css class instead of an id and/or `.on()` can help here too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.setTimeout() for this. setTimeout returns a timeoutID that you can use to cancel the action before it's triggered.

If you are setting the timeout inside a jquery callback function, you should wrap the target function call into an anonymous function, instead of just entering the target function name.

```
var delay = 3000;
var timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){base64_toField();},delay);

//if you need to cancel the function call before it's triggered:
clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

Edit: I just read that your form submits without the 3 second delay. you should suppress the default action on the event:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff
}
```